# Html: BarbaJS Slider transition

Tags: html, barbajs

I am using this library for the first time, my problem is that the slider works when the page is first loaded. The slider does not work when I switch to another page and return to the scroll page again. please can you help me i'm new here about `barba js`, i don't know how to do it, i will be very happy if you help her.

As shown in the picture. the first image works when the page loads. Doesn't work on 2 images

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my research has yielded results. maybe i will help someone
for different pages. Js should be called.

```
barba.hooks.afterEnter((data) => {
jQuery.getScript("jsname.js");
});
```